# Use the Epsilon Delta Definition to Show that the limit of $\sqrt{x}$ as $x$ goes to $0$ from above $= 0$.

Tags: calculus

I have no idea how to approach this, since everything is just $0$. Please post a walkthrough solution and explain your reasoning behind each step.

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is my proof. I haven't looked at any solutions yet so please specify whether or not I have proved it correctly.

We want to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ then it is possible to find a $\delta > 0$, such that if $x$ has distance at most $\delta$ from $0$ then $f(0)$ has at most distance epsilon from $\sqrt{x}$.

If $0 <= |x - 0| < \delta$ then $|\sqrt{x} - 0| < \epsilon$.

$=> |\sqrt(x)| < \epsilon$
$=> \sqrt{x} < \epsilon$ Since $\sqrt{x}$ is equal to or greater than $0$.
$=> x < \epsilon^2$

Let $\delta = \epsilon^2$

$0 <= |x| < \delta$
$, 0 <= |x| < \epsilon^2$
$, 0 <= \sqrt{|x|} < \epsilon$
$, 0 <= |\sqrt{x}| < \epsilon$ Since $|x|$ is greater than or equal to $0$.
$, 0 <= \sqrt{x} < \epsilon$ Since $|x|$ is greater than or equal to $0$.

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Even if you can't think of anything to try, writing out definitions can help. In general, stackexchange users don't post walkthrough solutions for homework problems. They aren't here to do your homework!

Comment: How is everything zero? I will get you started, and you can proceed with the proof. Suppose there is $\epsilon > 0$. We want to find small enough $x$ such that $\sqrt{x} < \epsilon$. Square both sides. I'll leave it here.

Comment: I have watched the following videos by PatrickJMT to try and understand what to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0ax2x2_Em0 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rIHSOQhhwI . However, when I use the same method, I just get 0s. I'm not sure how to tackle this.

Comment: I've updated the post with my reasoning thus far. You can see why I'm stuck - the 0s are meaningless and simply leave me with |x| and |sqrt(x)|! Its not like the other examples I've seen.

Comment: Have you successfully done and delta epsilon definition to determine limits before?  This is one of the easiest to do.  "Everything being just 0" shoul simply make everything much easy.  So long as $\delta \le \epsilon^2$ everything will work.

Comment: What do you mean you "just get zeros"?  And why is that a problem?

Comment: @fleablood I have done example problems like those shown in the above videos. However, I do not understand what is conceptually going on for sqrt(x). As you said, everything is just 0 so it seems like the method for proving it breaks down. My entire point of this post is for someone to explain it and walk me through a solution step-by-step. I am not just looking for an answer - I want to develop an understanding for what is going on.

Comment: |x| = |x - 0|.  And |sqrt x | = |\sqrt x -0|.  That's perfectly fine!  It's not any different.  For all |x - 0| < delta, |sqrt x - 0| < epsilon.  That is what you *want*.

Comment: @fleablood Hmm. Then what is there left to prove? I don't understand :S

Comment: Well you have to prove that for every $epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta $ so that $|x| <\delta \implies |\sqrt {x}| < \epsilon $...

Comment: @fleablood I think I got the correct proof. :D What do you think?

Comment: It's correct.  Good job.  But minor points.  It should be $0 \le |whatever|< greekletter$ rather than $0 < |whatever|<\greekletter $.  We want to allow equaling 0.

Comment: @fleablood YAY!!!!!!! :)!!!!!!! I fixed all the < to <=. Thank you so much for your help! I can feel that I have a deeper understanding now! Math is awesome and this website is awesome. Thank you again!!!!!!!!!!!! :) I wish you all the best!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *exactly* the same!

We want $|\sqrt {x} - 0| < \epsilon $ and want to find a $\delta$ that will make that happen.

So $|\sqrt {x} - 0| < \epsilon $ will be true whenever $|\sqrt {x}| < \epsilon $ which will be true when $|x| < \epsilon^2$.  Which is true whenever $|x -0 |< \epsilon^2$.

So we set $\delta \le \epsilon^2$.

If $|x -0| = |x| <\delta$ then $|\sqrt {x} -0| = |\sqrt {x}|=\sqrt {|x|}< \sqrt {\delta}\le \epsilon $.

That's it.  There's nothing different!  If anything this are easier.

If you *want* to make it hard:

We want $|\sqrt {x} - L| < \epsilon $

The will happen if $|\sqrt {x}| < |L-\epsilon|$

So we want $|x| < |L^2 - 2L\epsilon + \epsilon^2|$

So we want $|x -a| <  =  ||L^2 - 2L\epsilon + \epsilon^2|-a|$

So we want $\delta =||L^2 - 2L\epsilon +\epsilon^2| -a| =| |0^2l -2*0\epsilon +\epsilon^2|-0|=||0-0+\epsilon^2|-0|=\epsilon^2$.

Comment: I have posted my proof before looking at yours. I would appreciate it if you could look over it.

Comment: Your proof is good.